# eclipse GetAnnotation returns @NonNull

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to use the Eclipse `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull` annotations and i don't understand this

method signature:

```
@NonNull MyAnnotation java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotation(Class<@NonNull MyAnnotation> annotationClass)
```

```
for loop:
if(field.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class)!=null)
    continue;
```

Eclipse declares the following code dead code

```
try{
```

Why does eclipse think the `getAnnotation` class returns `@NonNull`?
The docs clearly state it can return `null`.

I have verified via a debugger that the code is not dead, stepping trough.

**EDIT:**
I do not use @NonNullByDefault on any package

I tried:

- adding `@Nullable` to MyAnnotation, i get `The nullness annotation 'Nullable' is not applicable at this location`
- `@Nullable MyAnnotation n=field.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);`
  still same problem

Comment: Although the javadocs might state it the signature states it is `@NonNull` so according to the code analysis and compiler hints (the `@NonNull`) the code shouldn't return `null`. If it does the `@NotNull` is in the wrong place.

Comment: yes the signature @NonNull is in the wrong place, the question is why? and how to correct it?

Comment: Remove it. as apparently you put it there or the Eclipse compiler made synthetic method or something. I also assume that [this is the original signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-). So unless you are using a different JDK (or maybe an eclips specific one those annotations aren't even there).

Comment: I did not put anything there. The signature is on a JDK function. And the MyAnnotation class does not have any annotations about Null.

Comment: It isn't. There is no Eclipse specific annotation in the JDK (see my link). So either you have a custom JDK or Eclipse tries to be smart.

Comment: I think Eclipse tries to be smart. I do not know what to delete. I have no control about the signature of JDK functions. I tried adding @Nullable to MyAnnotation but i get "The nullness annotation 'Nullable' is not applicable at this location"

Comment: I don't get what is it you are trying to do? Why are you importing that annotation?

Comment: Only to show which one i am talking about, there are other implementations.

Comment: I am trying to get rid of the dead code warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got rid of the warning by adding the first line:

```
Class<MyAnnotation> c = MyAnnotation.class;

if(field.getAnnotation(c)!=null)
    continue;
```

After that i do not get the dead code warning.

Somehow Eclipse is adding the @NonNull annotation automatically to MyAnnotation.